# Equivalent of index and match in R

Tags: r

I've been looking at previous solutions to an equivalent of excel's index and match, and can't get any to work with my data in R.
I've provided an example dataset below. There are 4 samples and measurements are a frequency count of 'CAGs' i.e. in sample A01 there are 6485 counts of 13 CAGs. I've managed to calculate the modal CAG (value in CAG for the highest measurement in each column). I've also managed to calculate summary stats on the data using psych(). I'm then using these results to calculate skewness using (mean-mode)/sd. 
Each sample has a control sample e.g. A02's control sample is A01. I'd also like to calculate skewness using the control mode i.e. (mean-ctrlmode)/sd. To achieve this I need to look up and return the mode of the control sample into the results table. I've indicated below where I'm stuck. Would be grateful for your help!

```
#Data set
data <- data.frame(CAG = c(13, 14, 15, 17), 
               A01 = c(6485,35,132, 12), 
               A02 = c(0,42,56, 4),
               A03 = c(33,5014,2221, 18),
               A04 = c(106,89,436, 11))

settings <- data.frame(samples = c('A01', 'A02', 'A03', 'A04'),
                   control = c('A01', 'A01', 'A03', 'A03')) 

#Mode
samplemode <- data.frame(samples = c('A01', 'A02', 'A03', 'A04'),
               samplemode = (data[sapply(data[2:ncol(data)], which.max), ]$CAG))

#Summary statistics
sumstats <- sapply(data[, 2:ncol(data)], function(x) {
  data_e <- rep(data$CAG, x)
  library(psych)
  data.frame(
    describe(data_e)
  )
})

sumstats <- as.data.frame(t(sumstats))

sumstats[] <- lapply(sumstats, function(x) {
  as.numeric(x)
})

# Results table
results <- data.frame(samples = settings$samples, 
                  samplemode = samplemode$samplemode, 
                  control = settings$control, 
                 ctrlmode = samplemode$samplemode[results$controls =     samplemode$samples], #THIS IS WHERE I'M HAVING TROUBLE
                  sumstats)


# Skewness
results$skewmode <- (results$mean - results$samplemode) / results$sd
results$skewctrlmode <- (results$mean - results$ctrlmode) / results$sd

#Expected results
expected <- data.frame(samples = settings$samples,
                   skewmode = c(0.1565726, -0.4903837, 0.6321606, -0.5270822), 
                   skewctrlmode = c(0.1565726, 2.4519186, 0.6321606, 0.6857736))
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Using 

results$skewmode <- (results$mean - results$samplemode) / results$sd

the results are: 0.1565726, -0.4903837, 0.6321606, -0.5270822

Using control modes it should be:

0.1565726, 2.4519186, 0.6321606, 0.6857736

Comment: Please add a data.frame in your question with the actual data of your desired result.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
results <- data.frame(samples = settings$samples, 
                      samplemode = samplemode$samplemode, 
                      control = settings$control, 
                      ctrlmode = samplemode$samplemode[match(settings$control,
                                                             samplemode$samples)],
                      sumstats)

results$skewmode <- (results$mean - results$samplemode) / results$sd
results$skewctrlmode <- (results$mean - results$ctrlmode) / results$sd

    samples samplemode control ctrlmode vars    n     mean        sd median  trimmed mad min max range       skew   kurtosis
A01     A01         13     A01       13    1 6664 13.05207 0.3325666     13 13.00000   0  13  17     4  7.1106921 56.4222321
A02     A02         15     A01       13    1  102 14.66667 0.6797398     15 14.60976   0  14  17     3  1.2624977  2.8577171
A03     A03         14     A03       14    1 7286 14.30771 0.4867646     14 14.25918   0  13  17     4  1.0332600  0.9050386
A04     A04         15     A03       14    1  642 14.56542 0.8245004     15 14.66342   0  13  17     4 -0.6341769  0.5311286
             se   skewmode skewctrlmode
A01 0.004073907  0.1565726    0.1565726
A02 0.067304270 -0.4903837    2.4519186
A03 0.005702620  0.6321606    0.6321606
A04 0.032540433 -0.5270822    0.6857736
```